# How do I install USB driver with my application at the same time?

Tags: usb, driver, inno-setup

I use inno setup to release my application and it works fine. But now I need to install the USB driver (I have the inf file) at the same time. Can you show me how to do this? Please refer to the following for my current inno setup .iss file.

```
#define MyAppName "SAMPLE"
#define MyAppVersion "1.20"
#define MyAppExeName "SAMPLE.exe"

[Setup]
AppId={#MyAppName}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
DefaultDirName={userdocs}\{#MyAppName}
DefaultGroupName={#MyAppName}
OutputDir=E:\Temp\Inno\Easy_Power_Beta_120
OutputBaseFilename=SAMPLE-Beta_1_20-setup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
Source: "E:\Bitbucket\EA2015\bin\Debug\SAMPLE.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "E:\Bitbucket\EA2015\bin\Debug\cmd.ini"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "E:\Bitbucket\EA2015\bin\Debug\default.png"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
…

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

I google lots of articles but still can’t figure it out.
Please feel free to contact me if you have any question. Really appreciate your help!

Eric

Answer (score 0):

Based on the info in [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557251(v=vs.85).aspx) it should be possible to create the appropriate [Run]-Entry.
Assuming your .INF-File has a DefaultInstall-section, it should probably be something like:

```
[Run]
Filename: "RUNDLL32.EXE"; Parameters: "SETUPAPI.DLL,InstallHinfSection DefaultInstall 132 path-to-inf\infname.inf"
```